# Hand-me-downs from a dead person

Tags: clothing, death

What's the story with using the clothing/shoes of a person who died? Does Jewish custom forbid such a thing?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20637

Comment: That covers the shoes.  But if the suit fits - wear it! Or tailor it and wear it-as long as it's taken from a wardrobe and not a body.  One thing to take into account is that in ancient days, the average person had fewer clothes, except for the upper classes.  I think there's at least one person mentioned in the Talmud that had only one good Shabbos garment that he shared with his wife(Gang?) The Torah in Exodus 22 mentions returning a pledged garment to a poor man at nightfall-just the basics like food, clothing, and shelter were rarer then.

Comment: The only thing I'm aware of that's explicitly mentioned is that you may not wear something that is alredy on the dead person, such as his tallit or kittel. I've been wearing lots of clothing inherytances from my grandfather, esp. his ties. When I do, I hear him tell me how good I look.